Man buys a book on how to find ghosts
This is a movie I watched quite some time ago and I can't remember the title of it. I can only remember some scenes from it. (I'm not sure if everything here is accurate though).
It's an Asian horror movie and there's a man who buys a book about how to see ghosts. The shopkeeper warns him to never open it up to the last page. While he was sleeping, the wind blows the book to the last page and he wakes up to see it and in reality, at the end page is just a price tag that says the book is worth less than what he paid for it.
There's also a scene where he goes with his friends to a crossroad with lots of food. They have to tap at bowls with chopsticks so the ghosts who come to eat the food won't mind them. Eventually, they panic and tap at the bowls violently and they break. Out of desperation, one of the characters begins tapping the chopsticks in his teeth and the ghosts continue eating.
Another scene is where a character accidentally opens her umbrella in a bus. Later, she sees a severed head rolling in the bus and it stops by her feet. She panics and the person next to her asked her why she was freaking out. When she looked down, the head turned into a simple ball.
I don't remember any more scenes, but if you can help me find this movie's title, it'll really help!

This is The Eye 10 AKA The Eye Infinity (which is actually the third Eye movie) from 2005. All the scenes you've mentioned are there: A man buys a ghost book and he's warned never to flip to the last page, and when he does, he finds out it's cheaper than he thought; a group of friends taps bowls to see ghosts until the bowls break, and then one of them taps his teeth instead; and a girl with an umbrella on a bus thinks she sees a severed head, but it's just a ball. Most of the scenes are also detailed in the Wiki page. The trailer is available on Youtube, and here's a still from the bowl scene:

